# How can I generate horizontal JavaScript numbers so that they correspond to the days of the month

Tags: javascript, for-loop, web, calendar

This can write out the number vertically but not horizontal and it doesn't give the 7 14 21 28 number breaks

```js
const getDay = document.getElementById('days');
const getWeek = document.getElementById('week');
getWeek.innerHTML = '<tr><th>H</th><th>K</th><th>Sz</th><th>Cs</th><th>P</th><th>Sz</th><th>V</th></tr>';
for (let i = 1; i < 32; i++) {
  getDay.innerHTML += ' <tr><td id="' + i + 'day" class="days" onclick="open' + i + '()">' + i + '</td>';

  if (i == 7) {
    getDay.innerHTML += '</tr>';
  }
  if (i == 14) {
    getDay.innerHTML += '<tr></tr>';
  }
  if (i == 21) {
    getDay.innerHTML += '<tr></tr>';
  }

  if (i == 28) {
    getDay.innerHTML += '<tr></tr>';
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead id="week"></thead>
  <tbody id="days"></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add tags without end tags to innerHTML. The browser immediately closes the tag

Also you pushed the tr's in the wrong order. Close first, then open

Lastly use an eventListener on the tbody to handle the clicks

```js
const open = dayNum => {
  console.log(dayNum);
};
const getDay = document.getElementById('days');
const getWeek = document.getElementById('week');
getWeek.innerHTML = '<tr><th>H</th><th>K</th><th>Sz</th><th>Cs</th><th>P</th><th>Sz</th><th>V</th></tr>';
const dayArr = ['<tr>']; // start with a open row
for (let i = 1; i < 32; i++) {
  dayArr.push('<td id="' + i + 'day" class="days">' + i + '</td>');
  if (i % 7  == 0) dayArr.push('</tr><tr>'); // close and open the row
}
getDay.innerHTML = dayArr.join('');
getDay.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest('td'); // we clicked a cell
  if (!tgt) return; // leave if not a cell
  open(tgt.textContent);
})
```

```html
<table>
  <thead id="week"></thead>
  <tbody id="days"></tbody>
</table>
```